# Global Array of Structs, declare size in program and use globally without passing?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc, parameter-passing

Just for context, I am making a cache simulator as a C project. I need to declare a global double array of a struct, set the size of this global struct array in the program, and then use that global array in the project later on.

Here is a shortened up version of what I have:

```
// Declare globals
int mapping = 0;
int offset = 0;
int index = 0;

char* allocation;
char* writePolicy;

struct cache {
    int validBit;
    int dirtyBit;
    unsigned int tag;
    unsigned int nextToReplace;
    };

void analyzeParameters(char* line, int lineNum) {

switch(lineNum) {
        case 1:
            mapping = atoi(line);
        case 2:
            offset = atoi(line);
        case 3:
            index = atoi(line);
        case 4:
            allocation = malloc(4);
            strcpy(allocation, line);
        case 5:
            writePolicy = malloc(4);
            strcpy(writePolicy, line);
    }

}

setupCache() {
int numSets = 1 << index;

struct cache cache[mapping][numSets];

printf("Declared cache struct with size %d ", numSets);
printf("num of ways %d\n", mapping);

// initialize bits in cache to 0

int j;
int i;

for (j = 0; j < mapping; j++) { 
    for (i = 0; i < numSets; i++) {
        cache[j][i].validBit = 0;
        cache[j][i].dirtyBit = 0;
    }
}

}

void hitChecker() {

for (d = 0; d < mapping; d++) {
    if (cache[d][index].validBit == 1) {
        if (cache[d][index].tag == tag) { 
            //found a hit

            if (type == "r") {
            // hit with a read instruction.
            rhits++;


            }
            else if (type == "w") {
            // hit with a write instruction
            whits++;

            }
        }

        else {
        // tag in cache index is not equal to tag being checked

            if (type == "r") {
            // missed with a read instruction.
            rmisses++;

            }
            else if (type == "w") {
            // missed with a write instruction
            wmisses++;

            }
        }
    }
    else {
    //cache is not valid
    printf("Cache has not been validated");
    }
}

void main(int argc, char**argv) {

analyzeParameters(passInEachLineOfFile, this works not important);

setupCache();

hitChecker();

}
```

This works up until I try to utilize the cache struct. I declare it globally, set the size in setUpCache, and then in another method I want to use that double array declared globally. Is there a way I can use it globally or do I have to pass the struct around via method parameters?

Comment: `passInEachLineOfFile` How long are lines in a file?

Comment: Sorry, I was super unclear on that, I didnt want to take up much space. 

It is reading in a file with 5 lines. the first line is always the mapping of the cache, the second line is always the offset, the third line is always the index, and so on.

What i do is loop through each line in the file, along with a counter representing the line I'm in. If I'm in line one, I set the global int mapping to whatever that value is and so on. 

In my test scenario, line 1 is 1, line 2 is 5, and line 3 is 8. Those get passed in and set to the global ints

Comment: Being such unclear is ok. Not checking for overflow in `strcpy(writePolicy, line);` is not ok. You should `strlcpy(..., 4, line)` as you use `malloc(4)` to allocate memory. How/Where is `cache` variable declared inside `void hitChecker()` function scope?

Comment: Oh dear... `struct cache cache[mapping][numSets];` is declared local and so is not global. it doesn't exist anymore once the function exits...

Comment: @PaulOgilvie (Is that how I tag people? I'm a noob) That would make sense haha. Is there a way I can get that to be global, while being able to determine and declare the size globally?

Comment: [How can I dynamically allocate 2D-array in one allocate C](//stackoverflow.com/q/43710298) or [How do I work with dynamic multi-dimensional arrays in C?](//stackoverflow.com/q/917783)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `cache` as a global variable, declare it in the global scope, and *before* using it.

```
struct cache {
    int validBit;
    int dirtyBit;
    unsigned int tag;
    unsigned int nextToReplace;
    };

struct cache cache[mapping][numSets];
```

It's not a good idea to put a variable in the global scope if you can avoid it.

Here, to **"encapsulate"** the caching feature, I suggest to use rather a **static** variable in a **separate file** with all cache-related functions, to let it within a **"file" scope**. Since `mapping`, `offset` and `index` are arguments from the outside of your caching functions, pass them as parameters.

```
// cache-lib.c

// Declare the struct in the c file, it's only needed here
struct cache {
        int validBit;
        int dirtyBit;
        unsigned int tag;
        unsigned int nextToReplace;
        };

static struct cache cache[mapping][numSets];

// Stores below variable here, in the "file" scope.
static mapping, offset, index;

// Below cache functions. Declare them an includable header.

/// setupCache() definition. Since it needs mapping, offset and index which
/// are retrieved from the outside, you can pass them as parameter.

void setupCache(int mapping, int offset, int index) {
  //// [...]
}

/// hitChecker. Maybe you need here to store extra variables
/// as "file-scope" ones like index and mapping
void hitChecker() {
  //// [...]
}
```

Finally, the header you would use everywhere you need your cache lib:

```
// cache-lib.h

void setupCache(int mapping, int offset, int index);
void hitChecker();
```

You may also include it in your `cache-lib.c` to not bother with issues related to the order of functions declaration.

Comment: `mapping` and `numSets` are not constants and are unknown at compile time.

Comment: Oh, would I still be able to declare that 
struct cache cache[mapping][numSets] globally, before I determine mapping and numSets from my methods?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, my answer isn't complete, it's just a little example.

Comment: Ooh, I'll try this out in a lil bit. Thanks for answering!

Comment: @Amessihel One quick silly question, but when you mention to 'Declare them(mapping, offset, and index) in an included header, would I scan the file in that header then?

To get my mapping and numSets variables, I'd need to run through my input file. I haven't used header files cuz I'm a C noob, but if I'm understanding it right, in my header file, I'd create a method to scan through my text file passed into the program as a command line argument. Then, I grab my global variables from the file, then those get passed into my .c project as globals?

Answer (score 1):

To have a global cache structure with run-time determined sizes, use:

```
int mapping, numsets;
struct cache **cache;
```

and:

```
void init(int nmaps, int nsets)
{
    cache=malloc(nmaps*sizeof(struct cache *));
    for (int i=0;i<nmaps;i++)
        cache[i]=malloc(nsets*sizeof(struct cache));
    mapping= nmaps;
    numsets= nsets;
}
```